# Charge density of an electric dipole and dipole density

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dipole, dipole-moment

I am trying to visualize in my head and understand how the concepts of electric dipole charge density and dipole density can be interpreted in space or in a coordinate system. In our lecture the formulas for the below listed cases are different from what I read in Wikipedia. I will derive the formulas similarly to what it was written in the lecture, and compare one of them with a result from the Wikipedia article on electric dipole moment. I will also be making statements regarding the different letters such as $\vec r_i, \vec r, \bar {\vec r}$ etc. in order to showcase whether my understanding of the formulas in a geometrical/spacial sense is correct. That way people who know and understand more about the topic, will be able to confirm or correct me.

Dipole : $\vec p=q\vec a$, $\vec a$ points from the negative charge to the positive.

Charge density of an electric point dipole:

For the moment for simplicity, I am considering that the negative charge is in the center of the reference frame.

$\rho_d(r)={lim}_{\vec a\rightarrow0, q\rightarrow \infty}{q[\delta(\vec r - \frac {\vec a} 2) - \delta(\vec r - \frac {\vec a} 2)]}$.

Via Taylor approximation we get:

$\rho_d(r)=-\vec p \nabla_r\delta(\vec r)$.

I assume that, in case the negative charge it's not in the origin then the above formula becomes:

$\rho_d(r)=-\vec p \nabla_r\delta(\vec r -\bar{\vec r})$. I am not sure whether this is correct or no, and if yes, I don't understand the expression I came up with.

Now for the dipole density ($\vec P$ is polarization) of a single electric dipole moment:

$\vec P(\vec r) = \vec p \delta(\vec r - \bar{\vec r}) \longrightarrow \vec p(\vec r)=\int_V \vec P(\vec r) \cdot d\bar V= \int_V \vec p \delta(\vec r - \bar{\vec r})d\bar V$.

$\rho_d(r)=-\vec p \nabla_r\delta(\vec r -\bar{\vec r}) = -\nabla_r\delta(\vec r -\bar{\vec r})\int_V \vec p\delta(\vec r - \bar{\vec r})d\bar V$.

To my understanding $\vec r$ represent the position where the electric dipole is located, while $\bar{\vec r}$ is a position vector who "moves" around the space when we integrate and when it's value is the same as $\vec r$ we are at the location of the dipole.

For many dipoles we have:

$\vec P(\vec r)= \Sigma_i \vec p_i \delta (\vec r - \bar{\vec r}_i)$.

My interpretation of this expression:

Each dipole is located somewhere in space, and has it's own position vector $\bar{\vec r}_i$. Then we have $\vec r$ which is a vector that "moves" in space, and whenever we integrate over all space and $\vec r = \bar{\vec r}_i$ we get the electric dipole moment of the dipole in positon $\bar{\vec r}_i$. But here is my confusion. Polarization is defined as the dipole density, nr. of dipoles per unit volume/surface/line. How exactly the above expression satisfies this definition?

And finally, for this case, we get for the  electric dipole moment:

$\vec p(\vec r) = \int _V\Sigma_i \vec p_i \delta (\vec r - \bar{\vec r}_i)d\bar V $

$\vec p(\vec r) = \Sigma_i\int _V \vec p_i \delta (\vec r - \bar{\vec r}_i)d\bar V $

$\vec p(\vec r)= \Sigma_i \vec p_i(\vec r)$.

In Wikipedia it is as follows:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/84137fe2945945a17bc068f5b3ef7d7c3c7fbf69

As you can see, in the Wikipedia article there is a vector difference which I don't have. How can I arrive at this expression from my own, in case I am correct?

If my solution to the dipole moment of many electric dipoles is correct, then is it implied that for a given amount of electric dipoles in a region, we also have a total electric dipole, which is the sum of the each electric dipole in the observed region, in other words:

$\vec p(\vec r)= \Sigma_i \vec p_i(\vec r)$.

Comment: please include the offending wikipedia formula in the question.

Comment: it's already there as a link

Comment: I know it's a link. Not everyone wants to follow a link. If you include the problem in the question, someone (e.g. me) can look at it and say, "Oh, I know that" and write an answer. As of now, no one has answered. If you include it, you may have more responses.